# Move elevated file to another location

Tags: c++, winapi

So here's the scenario. I'm writing an installer for my application. Here's the problem. The installer is elevated by the user to admin.

The process that is admin is currently running. My question is, how can I move this file to another location while it is running? If I try, I get the error "Access is denied" ... obviously since the file is already in use. It's important to take note that the file I want to move is itself. So like I can to take the current file and move itself to another directory.

So I want my program flow to be something like this:

```
request_admin_From_user() // done
start_admin_elevated_process() // done
move_admin_process_to_another_directory() // how? if the process is running..
```

Comment: *"How can I move admin processes to another location?"* What does this mean?

Comment: So like, the process that is admin is currently running. My question is, how can I move this file to another location while it is running? If I try, I get the error "Access is denied" ... obviously since the file is already in use. It's important to take note that the file I want to move is itself. So like I can to take the current file and move itself to another directory.

Comment: So your installer needs to move itself to the target folder? You should probably just make a copy - it's not generally possible to move an open file. This doesn't have anything to do with elevation though.

Comment: But lets say the user doesn't have permissions normally to copy the file in the first place? How can I copy it without requesting admin permissions? Also, take note, i'd like to copy the file into the PROGRAMFILES directory. How is this possible without admin permissions?

Comment: If the installer **is** elevated then it will be able to *copy* to Program Files, but it won't be able to *move* itself because it's running.

Comment: I know this. So what I'm asking is, how can move it prior to running it? If it's not possible to tell UAC to not run the process right away and instead move it first? That's the CORE of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process cannot **move** its own `.exe` file while it is running, but it can:

1. **copy** the file and then delete the original at a later time.
2. schedule a delayed move using [`MoveFileEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240.aspx) with the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` flag to perform the move on the next OS reboot.  This can also be used to delete a file on reboot.